# When did Ying Li lose her powers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

In *Shang-Chi and The Legend of The Ten Rings* (2021),The Iron Gang meets Ying Li, whose husband destroyed them:

> Ying Li (Says to Shang Chi): I'm going to talk to our guests.
>
> Shang Chi: But **you don't have your powers**.
>
> Ying Li: Shang-Chi, you have nothing to fear.

When did Ying Li lose her powers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ying Li explained this to the young Shang-Chi in a scene that begins at around eight minutes into the runtime of the movie.

> SHANG-CHI: If Dad’s rings were so powerful, how did you beat him?
>
> YING LI: **Where I’m from, we are empowered by the magic of the Great Protector. When you have the heart of our dragon, you can do some amazing things.**
>
> SHANG-CHI: Can you still do those things?
>
> YING LI: **I left those powers in Ta Lo with our dragon, but what I got in return is so much better.**